# Alternative solutions of an inequality problem

Tags: inequality

Let $x, y, z$ be distinct real numbers.
Prove $ \sqrt[3]{x - y} + \sqrt[3]{y - z} + \sqrt[3]{z - x} \neq 0$

I'm curious about different ways to solve this inequality.

My solution:

> Substitute $u = \sqrt[3]{x - y}, v = \sqrt[3]{y - z}, w = \sqrt[3]{z - x}$
>  Distinctness of $x, y, z$ now implies $u, v, w$ are non zero.
>  If we assume $u + v + w = 0$ and write $w = -u - v$ and substitute that into
>  $u^3 + v^3 + w^3 = 0$, it follows that $u^3 + v^3 = (u+v)^3$.
>  Expanding, we get $3uv(u+v) = 0$, a contradiction with $u, v, w$ being
>  non zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here's another way.  From 
$$a^3+b^3+c^3 = (a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)+3abc$$
So if $a+b+c=0$, then $a^3+b^3+c^3=3abc$. With $a = \sqrt[3]{x-y}, b = \sqrt[3]{y-z}, c = \sqrt[3]{z-x}$, 
$$\implies 0=3\sqrt[3]{(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)}$$
which is not possible as $x, y, z$ are all distinct.